# C# razor regex replace some occurrences of dot with 1/6 emspace

Tags: c#, regex

in a string whenever the following occurs

> ~A.~ ( tilde, then any single upper case letter, then dot, then tilde)

I want to replace the 'dot' with a 1/6 em space.
I have tried several things including this but its not doing what I want

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"/(~)([A-Z])(.~)/g", "$1$2&8198;~");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
~([A-Z])\.~
```

And replace this with

```
~$1\u2006~
```

The unicode spaces can be found [**here**](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), the appropriate replacement is sth. like `\u1234567889`.

---

As a whole snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string txt = "~A.~ ( tilde, then any single upper case letter, then dot, then tilde)";
        string pattern = "~([A-Z])\\.~";
        string replacement = "~$1\u2006~";
        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = rx.Replace(txt, replacement);
        Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
    }
}
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/jJ0ecF).

Comment: Thanks I just had to double escape the dot \\.